# SQL Server results organized by program, currency with total line

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure that pulls data from a SQL server database and produces records.  What I would like is for all the records for a particular program and currency with a total row underneath.  Currently the script has the total record before the results and it is not broken up by currency.  I tried to add Currency to the group by clause but that made things worse.

My script -

```
    DECLARE @runDate DateTime = '2020-05-19'
    SELECT
        t1.RecDate AS [RecDate]
        ,t1.Program AS [Program]
        ,t1.Currency AS [Currency]
        ,t1.SupplierName AS [SupplierName]
        ,t1.SupplierAccount AS [SupplierAccount]
        ,t1.RecStatus   AS [RecStatus]
        ,t4.Type        AS [TYPE]
        ,t1.Date        AS [PiDate]
        ,t1.DiscountedDate  AS [DiscountedDate]
        ,t1.PaymentAmount   AS [Payment]

    FROM orb_RootRecords t1
    LEFT JOIN orb_SupplierRecords t3 on t3.OrbianAccountId = t1.SupplierAccount
    LEFT JOIN orb_AccountType t4 on t4.Id = t3.AccountTypeId
    WHERE FLOOR(CAST(t1.RecDate as float)) = FLOOR(CAST(@runDate as float))
    --ORDER BY [SORT], [Program]    ,[CURRENCY] ,[RecDate] ,[SupplierName] ,[SupplierAccount],[RecStatus] ,[TYPE],[PiDate]  ,[DiscountedDate] ,[Payment]

    UNION
    SELECT null AS [RecDate], Program AS [Program], null AS [Currency], null AS [SupplierName], null AS [SupplierAccount], null AS [RecStatus], null AS [TYPE], null AS [PiDate], null AS [DiscountedDate]
    ,SUM (PaymentAmount) AS [Payment]
    FROM orb_RootRecords
    WHERE FLOOR(CAST(RecDate as float)) = FLOOR(CAST(@runDate as float))
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(Program, Currency)
    ORDER BY [Program]  ,[CURRENCY] ,[RecDate] ,[SupplierName] ,[SupplierAccount],[RecStatus] ,[TYPE],[PiDate]  ,[DiscountedDate] ,[Payment]

Output -
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    56062459.21
NULL    Charles River International Inc NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    29546.62
2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 Charles River International Inc USD C.H. Robinson Worldwide Inc.    6240000150  Scheduled Discount  Schedule    2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 5025.78
2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 Charles River International Inc USD Life Science Products, Inc  6240000230  Auto Discount   Auto    2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 2626.84
2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 Charles River International Inc USD LR Transport LLC (dba JKL Secure)   6240000130  Auto Discount   Auto    2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 18484.00
2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 Charles River International Inc USD Midwest Filtration LLC  6240000040  Auto Discount   Auto    2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 3410.00
NULL    General Mills Inc   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    28651.20
NULL    General Mills Inc   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    405646.05
NULL    General Mills Inc   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7467291.72
NULL    General Mills Inc   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7901588.97
2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 General Mills Inc   CAD Aliments Ultima Inc/Ultima Foods    6050001210  Scheduled Discount  Schedule    2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 2020-05-19 00:00:00.000 2004.82
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're selecting data and you're looking for an aggregation ( either `count()` or `sum()`) that group by program and currency, but also sum the total for each program, as well as grand total for all.

Given my own example of data looks like this

```
CATEGORY | CURRENCY | AMOUNT
A        | USD      | 1
A        | USD      | 1
A        | EUR      | 2
A        | EUR      | 2
B        | USD      | 2
B        | EUR      | 3
```

when you query your data like this

```
SELECT
    category,
    currency,
    SUM(AMOUNT) sales
FROM
    sales.tablesales
GROUP BY
ROLLUP(category, currency);
```

the result will be

```
CATEGORY | CURRENCY | AMOUNT
A        | USD      | 2
A        | EUR      | 4
A        | NULL     | 6
B        | USD      | 2
B        | EUR      | 3
B        | NULL     | 5
NULL     | NULL     | 8
```

Which could be interpreted as

1. Category A, Currency Null, means the total for category A
2. Category B, Currency Null, means the total for category A
3. Category Null, Currency Null, means grand total for all

Comment: Just a total for each program and currency, not a grand total for all the programs. So in your example: category A USD will have a total. A EUR with have it's own total.

Comment: Yes, it does, I have edited the sample data so there are 2 rows of category A and currency USD, as well as there are 2 rows of category A and currency EUR, they both will be aggregated for each program and currency